# 4cy automatic 1997 Toyota Camry. The windows won’t roll down and car will not start. The alarm keeps going off

Tags: electrical, diagnostics, cranks-wont-run

I have a 1997 Toyota Camry. After installing a new battery the cars alarm is going off and will not start it just cranks. I can’t even roll the windows down or unlock the doors. Any help